# Filtering 'overlay_intersects' with query builder of QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, query, query-builder

In order to filter a data and display only the part of the data that intersects another data, I knew the expression 'overlay_intersects' but this function does not seem to work with the query builder (right click on the layer -> properties -> Source).

How do I perform such a filter with the query builder?

What is the syntax to use with the query builder?

Is there any documentation/guidance?

Comment: The query builder use the syntax of the data provider (that mean that depending on your data some operation may or may not be possible and the same filter may require different syntax)